# Is mysql_escape_string not supposed to be used at all? If not, what is the alternative?

Tags: php, mysql

I've a bunch of code that is not sanitized properly.  The best way is to bind variables, and this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php says that mysql_escape_string is not supposed to be used (I am using 5.3.2) at all.

Will mysql_escape_string not work at all, in versions greater than 5.3.0?

Edit: I understand that binding is the best way, but there is a bunch of old code that needs to be sanitized.  so if I use mysql_escape_string, will it not work at all? Is it useless?

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` (note the _real_) MUST be used if you are not using prepared statements.  The old `mysql_escape_string()` is deprecated.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: **real** another win for the php function nameing department.

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use prepared/parameterized queries with something like PDO.  You can use MySQLi as well, if you want to stick to a more native way to interacting with MySQL.  With parameterized queries, the data is sent independently of the SQL, making it inherently safe as far as SQL injection is concerned.

If you are looking for a replacement for `mysql_escape_string()` directly, that would be `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  It is a drop-in replacement, and must be used if you care about security at all.

Comment: There is a bunch hof code that needs to be changed.  There is another version being worked on, that will have bind statements.  Is there a quick way to protect the DB in the mean time, without using bind?  Like simply wrapping all parameters with mysql_escape_string, for example?

Comment: The entire `mysql_*` API will be deprecated in the future.

Comment: there will however be sites using it for the next several decades

Comment: @user187809, Replace `mysql_escape_string()` with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.